# Elasticsearch what's the difference between null and empty value?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mapping, like this

```
{
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

about `name` field, in my original data the `name` can be empty `""`.
I have two choose to put the doc to ES:

```
{
    "id" : 6 ,
    "name" : ""
}
```

or

```
{
    "id" : 6 ,
    "name" : null
}
```

I don't need to search data like name == "" or name != "" or name == null or name != null.

I saw that a mount of `empty values` will cause the performance problem somewhere else. And saw that `null value` will not be index and search. So I want to put null field.

Is there any difference in my use case ?

Answer (score 0):

A field with an empty `""` string value will yield true to an [`exists` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html#exists-query-top-level-params), which means that even if your value doesn't really contain a value, for Elasticsearch it does.

The only way to tell ES that your field doesn't contain a value is by assigning null.

Comment: So  if  some fields  exist a mount of empty values , we should change this empty value to null ? the performance is better ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

An empty string is a string instance of zero length, whereas a null string has no value at all.